# How do I generating code-coverage for salesforce locally

Tags: git, salesforce, cloud, salesforce-communities

I am developing the automation for salesforce, We are maintaining the code into ORG as well as in GIT.

I am using Salesforce CLI, and the command used to generate code-coverage is "sfdx force:apex:test:run" which requires the code to be available in ORG.
We want the code-coverage task to be independent,
Is it possible to run the test classes locally? I got some reference on ANT tool but not sure if it will help.
I am fine with using some other programming tool as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running a "validate only" deployment (whether tests succeed or fail - it'll be all rolled back, nothing will actually change in the org). **You still need an org** for this, there's no completely local Apex server like you can have with Python/Java/PHP/C#...

Common pattern is to waste one sandbox for it, call it "CI" and have git commit hooks or proper test deployments in Azure Devops pipeline that try and validate the code. You could create an early warning "who broke the build" system that way.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_build_mdapi_staging.htm

mentions `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy --checkonly` flag

If you want to use "source" commands for scratch orgs etc - `sfdx force:source:deploy --checkonly`.

---

**Edit** to answer comment

Yes, you should be able to get coverage too.

The "normal" command to run tests takes a `-c` parameter similar to

```
sfdx force:apex:test:run -c --resultformat human --outputdir c:\redacted --loglevel error

(...)
=== Apex Code Coverage
ID                  NAME                       % COVERED           UNCOVERED LINES
──────────────────  ─────────────────────────  ──────────────────  ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
01p3L0000004OaKQAU  names                     100%
01p3L0000004OaUQAU  redacted                  100%
01q3L0000004CyWQAU  to                        100%
01q3L0000004DM4QAM  protect                   100%
01p3L0000004UZGQA2  the                       94.23076923076923%  16,17,18
01p3L0000004QNRQA2  innocent                  86.04651162790698%  116,119,131,132,146,147,148,149,151,152,153,154,163,164,165,166,202,243
(..)
```

A validate deployment can't use `-c` because it's already an alias for `--checkonly`. But you can do this

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy --zipfile myPackage.zip -c --testlevel RunLocalTests -w 1

=== Apex Code Coverage
NAME                       % COVERED  UNCOVERED LINES
─────────────────────────  ─────────  ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
names                      86%        116,119,131,132,146,147,148,149,151,152,153,154,163,164,165,166,202,243
redacted                  100%
to                        100%
protect                   100%
the                        94%        16,17,18
innocent                  100%

Total Test Time:  6992.0

Successfully validated the deployment
```

I'm not 100% sure because what I was deploying here was identical to what's already in the org, you'd have to try it. But I see no reason why it shouldn't work. It should be reporting coverage for what's in the deploy attempt, not what's already in.

Comment: Thanks for quick response @eyescream, Does this also gives me the cove coverage report?
I would like to import that report into SonarQube.